# Access to storage AndroidManifest in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-permissions

I wrote a code in Unity and its job is to read the music folder in the main internal files of the Android phone, and now I want to get permission to access personal files in Unity for Android, but how?
I wright this in android manifest but it was not work.

i read this in chat GPT but it was not work!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.